# Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Facebook.IsFacebookUserAuthenticated always returns false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use Facebook helper from microsoft-web-helpers with asp.net mvc 3 application, but IsFacebookUserAuthenticated always returns false.
Here is how I'm using the Facebook helper

1.Facebook class is initialized at App_start in the global.asax :

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Facebook.Initialize("170548793051973", "3dea9b919b560067aadf105d333a7523");
    }
```

2.Facebook initialization scripts and namespaces are loaded in _Layout.cshtml:

[image]

3.Facebook Login button in _LogOnPartial:

```
     @Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Facebook.LoginButton(registerUrl:"~/Account/Register", callbackUrl:"~Facebook/Login")
```

4.FacebookController with Login action:

using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;

namespace FacebookLoginSample.Controllers
{
    public class FacebookController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Facebook/

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        var isFacebookUserAuthenticated = Facebook.IsFacebookUserAuthenticated;
        return View();
    }
}
```

}

5.When I click the facebook login button at runtime page is redirected to facebook login where valid user and password are passed and page is redirected to Facebook/Login which is FacebookController Login Action. 
isFacebookUserAuthenticated  is allways false!

Any ideas?

Comment: The last time I checked that library it was out of date and no longer maintained. This may have changed since then, but I have had great success with the [Facebook C# SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-c%23-sdk).

Comment: Well, I'm talking about http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft-web-helpers which has version 1.15 from August 2011 and it looks up to date

Comment: No, I didn't. I switched to the facebook c# sdk(http://csharpsdk.org/).